# Custom API Endpoint get data from category

Tags: wordpress, api

im pretty stuck.. Im trying to get all post data from a specific category ID, using Wordpress REST API. But it dosen't output the content, only the ID & Title.. Cant see what I am doing wrong..

Heres the code:

```
/* Register Route  http://dev.mpblogg.se/wp-json/api/v1/feedposts/id */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'api/v1', '/feedposts/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getAllPostsfromCategory',
    ));
});


/* Get all posts from the specific Caetgory */
function getAllPostsfromCategory( $data ) {
$secret = '2lpMh5EHaEiavhMONpWD';
$qs = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])[0];
$qs = explode('=', $qs)[1];
if($qs != $secret){
    return false;
}
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'category' => $data['id'],
));

$returnArray = array();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    array_push($returnArray, array(
        'id'    =>      $post->ID,
        'title'     =>      $post->post_title,
        'content'   =>      $post->post_content
    ));
}

// die();

if(empty($posts)){
    return null;
}
return $returnArray;
}
```

The JSON output looks like this:

[image]

After changing to array_push($returnArray,$post); it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: there may be some double quote or single quote in your post content which causes the problem ... Try to output single post one by one and find which post content is making obstacles in your output.

Comment: Can you change and try `array_push($returnArray,$post)`  and show us the JSON output again ?

Comment: Yes i added i image how it looks. The content is empty.. but why??

Comment: thats weird, you are sure right the post_conent is not really empty in your database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual the answer why it didnt work is so dumb. Im not using the the_content.. Im using a custom field from ACF called post_excerpt. So I just added:

```
'excerpt'   =>  get_field('post_excerpt', $post->ID),
```

Now it works.. Sorry all, but thank's for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... here's a clue that I got from the array_push image that you shared. The last string of the JSON output reads:

> "filer": "raw"

This means that the resultant value would be stored as a raw, unfiltered content of the post.

So, you can try adding apply_filters() to the extracted content and see if it helps you display the required content.

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

This is used to apply the content filters to raw unfiltered post content, which usually comes from the use of $post->post_content .

Comment: As usual the answer why it didnt work is so dumb. Im not using the the_content.. Im using a custom field from ACF called post_excerpt. So I just added:

 'excerpt' => get_field('post_excerpt', $post->ID)

Now it works.. Sorry all..